# Connect to FTP over a VPN

Tags: openvpn, centos7, vsftpd

Good evening,

I'd like to request some help with a small mystery.
I have setup a Centos 7 server and would like to add a few 
administrative services for VPN users only.

It is a web facing server that publicly exposes port 80, 443 and 944.
Using 944 one can connect to openvpn, this works as expected.

OpenVPN reports it has assigned IP 10.8.0.6 to the connection.
Now, I have a vsftpd server configured to listen at 127.0.0.1:21,
but my openvpn client cannot find it, I have tried several different configurations but my knowledge of networking simply isn't sufficient
to solve this problem. Could anyone instruct me which logs, files and 
or other info you'd need to help me get a solution?

Do note, I understand that the VPN is a different address range and
I can imagine that the local routing changes whenever you connect to 
a VPN, I just can't seem to get my head around how to fix it and connect 
to the localhost of the remote server.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
To be clear, I followed this tutorial to get to this point: [link](http://www.tecmint.com/setup-openvpn-server-with-linux-and-windows-clients-in-centos-rhel/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your VSFTPD server is ONLY listening on 127.0.0.1 (not all interfaces, or specific interfaces), then you won't be able to connect to it from your VPN Connected system, you will only be able to connect to it from the ftp(and vpn in this case) server itself.

You have two choices:

1 - Setup an SSH port forwarding tunnel from your vpn client to the ftp server.
ssh -L 2121:localhost:21 user@hostname
In this example, you would then direct your FTP client to localhost:2121, and it would get tunneled to the SSH destination (your ftp server) on localhost:21. This is a little hack'ish, but would work.

2a - Change your FTP server to listen on more interfaces. Openvpn by default will use the tun0 interface, so you could possibly configure it to only listen on the openvpn interface, however, since openvpn can remove/add its interface based on its running state, some applications will complain if an interface you told it to listen on isn't available on startup. You should test this scenario before relying on it.

2b - Alternatively, you could just listen on ALL available interfaces, but you'd need to make sure your iptables rule will deny any traffic not specifically allowed by you. You would also need a rule allowing traffic from your VPN.

Without seeing your exact iptables rules, it seems likely that either 2a or 2b would benefit from rules that look something like this:

iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack -i tun0 --ctstate NEW -m tcp -p tcp --match multiport --dports 21,22,80,443 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "tun0 VPN traffic"

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

Some iptables notes: the I and A are "insert" and "append" respectively, so insert would go at the beginning of the list, and append would go at the end. I like to use the "multiport" and "comment" modules, to make my iptables rules a little cleaner, but those are optional, and you can find other documentation out there showing how to use a slightly more vanilla iptables command.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I do not use iptables. Could you provide the details for firewalld? I can provide the ip route output for instance?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a firewalld guy, but the basic concept is that you want to allow ports you care about on your VPN interface tun0, and have a default deny at the end.

Comment: Did some research and the idea is clear. However, the ftp server cannot be configured to single out a specific interface and the part I still don't get is what the 10.8.0.1 network range actually means. To summarize your advice: it boils down to leaving the ip addressing alone and configuring the interface to allow only some connections, correct? My main concern is, won't that block all other traffic (the webserver) for users without the VPN? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10.8.0.X network is used by openvpn. It assigns vpn clients IP's from that subnet, and it assigns an ip address to the tun0 interface from that range. That tun0 ip address is used as the default gateway for connected clients.

Since you only have your ftp server running on 127.0.0.1, it isn't accessible from other interfaces. You need to have it listen on an interface that is networked (lo interface is special, and only accessible from localhost). It doesn't matter whether it listens on tun0, or one of your other interfaces (like eth0), as long as the firewall rules allow access from tun0

Comment: Yes, I see. The problem is that I cannot get vsftpd working with another ip address and therefore cannot change the interface it listens on. Your answer clarifies why the connection fails but it does not actually solve the problem. I'll go hunting again and will report back with the found solution. Thanks a bunch for your time!